# Number Analogy Problem

Tags: number-sequence

$ \frac{73}{67}: \frac{57}{55}::\frac{93}{87}: $ ?

Options are :

(1) $\frac{47}{67}$

(2) $\frac{53}{57}$

(3) $\frac{63}{61}$

(4) $\frac{73}{71}$

Source: NTSE 2016-17 Examination Bengaluru

Comment: From NTSE Stage 1 examinations conducted at Bengaluru, India 2016-2017. I know the correct answer and can give it if required, but I don't know the reasoning behind it.

Comment: OK, excellent. Could you please edit into the question the information about where it comes from? Sorry to be picky about this, but we try to be scrupulous about attribution here...

Comment: (and Welcome to Puzzling!)

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 3):

> 4)73/71

There is a pattern in the given fractions

> 73-67 is 6 and 93-87 is also 6.
>  73,67 are both prime and (57,55),(93,87) are composite.
>  the next fraction should have both prime numbers
>  with the difference between the numbers as 2 (57-55).

Answer (score 1):

Going by the title of this puzzle and mathematically, answer could be

> (4) 73/71

As,

> All the given fractions are >1 and so the answer should be and fractions are made up entirely of prime numbers / composite numbers but not a mix. Hence option (4).